# Does Autofac Multitenant container works with IIndex<Key, Value>?

Tags: .net, wpf, dependency-injection, autofac, multi-tenant

In my WPF app I use Multitenancy (2 tenants).

To simplify question, I'll show example:

```
   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
   builder.RegisterModule<Module1>();
   var container = builder.Build();
   var singletonClass = container.Resolve<SingletonClass>();
   ITenantIdentificationStrategy strategy = new TenantIdentificationStrategy(singletonClass);
   MultitenantContainer multitenantContainer = new MultitenantContainer(strategy, container);
   multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant("A", c => c.RegisterModule<Module2>());
   multitenantContainer.ConfigureTenant("B", c => c.RegisterModule<Module3>());
   Interface1 interface1 = multitenantContainer.Resolve<Interface1>();
   interface1.foo();
```

Interface1 - not depended on tenants (registered in Module1),
TenantIdentificationStrategy - by SingletonClass provides TenantId,
Module2 and Module3 - register different classes with shared Interface2 by key.

Interface1 has such implementation:

```
internal class Service1 : Interface1
{
   private readonly IIndex<string, Interface2> index;
   private readonly SingletonClass singletonClass;

   public Service1(IIndex<string, Interface2> index, SingletonClass singletonClass)
   {
       this.index = index;
       this.singletonClass = singletonClass;
   }

   public void foo()
   {
       singletonClass.Id = "A";
       if (index.TryGetValue("key", out var b))
       {
       }
       else
       {
       }
   }
}
```

IIndex doesn't return service. And I noticed that it doesn't even enter TenantIdStrategy.
I didn't find any info about Multitenancy and IIndex in the internet.
Please, help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a compiler to test this out, my gut is the problem is here:

```cs
   public void foo()
   {
       singletonClass.Id = "A";
       if (index.TryGetValue("key", out var b))
       {
       }
       else
       {
       }
   }
```

The question description says the tenant ID is coming from your singleton class.

The problem here is that you're setting the tenant ID in your strategy *after* the `Service1` class has been resolved. **The tenant ID needs to be available at resolve time.** `IIndex` is not "deferred resolution" - it will use the tenant ID strategy and resolve from the tenant scope *at the time it's injected into `Service1` constructor*.

Set the singleton class before calling `Resolve<T>` and I bet it works as expected.

Comment: You're right, but in my real app, I will get TenantId later, than this service is resolved. I can add IIndex to separate service (Resolver), but I don't know how to add this resolver to DI as Transient(as in Microsoft DI), like resolve it when it's called.

Comment: If you won't know until too late, you'll have to pass the whole multitenant container into this service and do a manual resolve call. You won't be able to do the whole thing with DI only.